# I know python dict is order less but why I am getting keys in same order "always"

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `dict` named `tmp`:

```
>>> tmp
{1: 'ONE', 2: 'TWO', 3: 'THREE'}
>>> type(tmp)
<type 'dict'>
```

I iterated through this `dict` twenty times and on all iterations I got keys list in same order.

```
>>> for i in range(20):
...   print tmp.keys()
... 
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

I know python dict is order less **but** why I am getting keys in **same order "always"**?

Comment: The order is unspecified... that doesn't mean random.

Answer (score 4):

You don't modify `tmp` between calls to `tmp.keys()`, so the order of the keys never changes.

[From the docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

> If `items()`, `keys()`, `values()`, `iteritems()`, `iterkeys()`, and `itervalues()` are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond. This allows the creation of `(value, key)` pairs using `zip()`: `pairs = zip(d.values(), d.keys())`. The same relationship holds for the `iterkeys()` and `itervalues()` methods: `pairs = zip(d.itervalues(), d.iterkeys())` provides the same value for pairs. Another way to create the same list is `pairs = [(v, k) for (k, v) in d.iteritems()]`.

Answer (score 2):

Because otherwise, this wouldn't work:

```
for key, value in zip(d.keys(), d.values()):
    ...
```

And various similar problems.

Python's dict and set types are guaranteed to have the same iteration order *as long as the dict/set isn't modified*.  Try adding other values to `tmp` and chances are you'll get a different order next time.

(*However*, note that small integers as keys are not a particularly great example of how this works — small integers hash to themselves in CPython, so they're probably more likely to pop out in numerical order.  Try some strings.)

Comment: But, it's easier to just do: `for i,j in d.items()`

Comment: yes, but sometimes you want to do something fancier with the keys and values, for whatever reason.  (anyway, how do you think `dict.items` is implemented?)

Answer (score 1):

Upon creating a dict, python creates its own order. Everytime you call the `.keys()` or `.values()` or `.items()`, you will get the result unordered in the *same* order everytime as long as you don't modify the dictionary. Hope that makes sense.

As you can see in the example below, even though I create the dictionary with a specific order, python reorders the dictionary. However, after that, the order always stays the same (as long as you don't modify the dictionary).

```
a = {'apple' : 'fruit', 'car' : 'vehicle', 'onion' : 'vegetable'}

print a

for i in range(5):
    print a.keys()

[OUTPUT]
{'car': 'vehicle', 'apple': 'fruit', 'onion': 'vegetable'}
['car', 'apple', 'onion']
['car', 'apple', 'onion']
['car', 'apple', 'onion']
['car', 'apple', 'onion']
['car', 'apple', 'onion']
```

Comment: it's not about efficiency; it's just the nature of hash tables.

Comment: It's not exactly "the order Python deems most efficient", it's just a hash table with a basic key collision routine.  And the order can change after insertion if a later insertion or deletion causes the dict to be resized.  But yeah, for a steady state dict, the entries will remain in the same order, at least in CPython (though it's really an implementation detail of the interpreter, not something guaranteed by language spec).

Comment: the language absolutely guarantees the order is stable between modifications: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Comment: I really need to reiterate that the order does NOT always stay the same.  If the dictionary is expanded or shrunk enough that the underlying hash table is resized by the interpreter, order can very well change.

Answer (score 1):

Since python dict is implemented as Hash Table, the order of key is based on its hash value, which decides which slot is used to store 'key/value' pair.

For integer value as the key, the hash value is simply the integer itself

```
>>> map(hash, [1,2,3])
[1,2,3]
```

Here what you use as key is consecutive int, their hash value is also consecutive, there is high chance that the underneath hash algorithm choose the consecutive slots to store 'key/value' pairs, that's why you see the same order as you create the dict. Here is a simple counterexample:

```
>>> tmp = {1:1, 5:5, 10:10}
>>> tmp.keys()
[1, 10, 5]
```

And of course during the loop, you don't modify the dictionary, which will not cause hash table to get resized, so the order remains.

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...   print tmp.keys()
[1, 10, 5]
[1, 10, 5]
[1, 10, 5]
[1, 10, 5]
[1, 10, 5]
```

If you are interested in the detailed implementation in Python, check this nice article:
[Python dictionary implementation](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/)