# Does python list(set(a)) change its order every time?

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of 5 million string elements, which are stored as a pickle object.

```
a = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_learning_theory','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_processing','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubesort','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort']
```

To remove duplicates, I use `set(a)`, then I made it a list again through `list(set(a))`.

My question is:

Even if I restart python, and read the list from the pickle file, will the order of `list(set(a))` be the same every time?

I'm eager to know how this hash -> list ordering works.

---

I tested with a small dataset and it seems to have a consistent ordering.

```
In [50]: a = ['x','y','z','k']

In [51]: a
['x', 'y', 'z', 'k']

In [52]: list(set(a))
['y', 'x', 'k', 'z']

In [53]: b=list(set(a))

In [54]: list(set(b))
['y', 'x', 'k', 'z']

In [55]: del b

In [56]: b=list(set(a))

In [57]: b
['y', 'x', 'k', 'z']
```

Comment: There is definitely a random element involved in the hashing procedure.

Comment: For starters, the order of the hash isn't guaranteed, so the order of the list wouldn't be guaranteed either.

Comment: I guess you can use [ordered-set](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordered-set) instead of `set`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3:  I disagree with the dupe.  The dupe talks about dictionaries; this is asking about the order of a `list(set(l))`.

Comment: Dictionaries are sets with attached values. The hashing is the same.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 this is question about hash-to-list ordering, do you still think it's the same?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I first marked this question as a duplicate but I just realized that it's slightly different with the dup and other similar questions as well. The question's tops says that clearly.

Comment: Also see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629023/key-order-in-python-dictionaries#comment48032902_5629023) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482872/i-know-python-dict-is-order-less-but-why-i-am-getting-keys-in-same-order-always) and the implementation detail in [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

Comment: @DDDrupal Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537090/whats-the-logic-behind-pythons-hash-function-order if you want to understand the logic, but about changing the order over the time, if you don't modify the list the order would be same over the time.

Comment: As the question I linked above says, in the documentation the answer points to, it depends on the "history of insertions and deletions." I'd say that means that if you build it in the exact same way you'll get the exact same iteration order. Note that it also says that it's implementation-dependent, so your program shouldn't rely on this ordering.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'd argue that even if the answer is the same as for dicts, the explanation that sets, and list(set(l)) will do the same thing is enough to make this not a dupe.

Comment: This question Y may be about sets while the other question Y is about dictionaries, but question X is about hash tables (see the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Ignoring a useful resource because of a trivial difference like that would be a disservice.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That's definitely true, but if I'm wondering what order my list(set(l)) will be in, an answer explaining that a set is a hash table, and linking to the explanation of dictionary/hash table ordering (maybe with a summary, maybe not), is substantially more useful than a link to a question about dicts that I may not understand as being related. There may already be a dupe target that does the same thing.

Comment: Some of these comments are about the semantics of the question not the question. please delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest an auxiliary `set()` to ensure unicity when adding items on the list, thus preserving the order of your `list()`, and not storing the `set()` per se.

First, load your list and create a set with the contents
Before adding items to your list, check that they are not in the set (much faster search using "in" from the set rather than the list, specially if there are many elements)
Pickle your list, the order will be exactly the one you want

Drawback: takes twice as much memory than handling only a `set()`